# Relation between a probability problem and determinant

Tags: probability, matrices, random-walk

Considering a random walk problem with two walls that can absorbing the particle, i.e. a particle moves randomly on a number axis and when it moves to the walls it will be absorbed.

Let **p** denotes the probability that in one move the particle moves right and the locations of the two walls are $x=0,\ x=a+b$ respectively. We assume that the particle won't keep still in each move and thus **1-p** is the probability of moving left.

By total probability formula we can calculate the probability of being absorbed by the walls   on $x=a+b$ with initial location $x=n\ (n\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,a+b\})$
$$q_{n} = \frac{1-(\frac{q}{p})^n}{1-(\frac{q}{p})^{a+b}}$$
where $q=1-p$.

I find the form of numerator and dominator pretty similar to the determinant of a special matrix
$$D_n = \left[\begin{matrix}
1+(\frac{q}{p}) & \frac{q}{p} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & 1+(\frac{q}{p}) & \frac{q}{p} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1+(\frac{q}{p}) & \frac{q}{p} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1+(\frac{q}{p}) & \frac{q}{p} \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 1 & 1+(\frac{q}{p}) 
\end{matrix}\right]_{n\times n}
$$
and $det(D_n) = \frac{1-(\frac{q}{p})^n}{1-(\frac{q}{p})}$. Thus
$$q_n = \frac{det(D_n)}{det(D_{a+b})}$$

It seems that for every random walk process with initial location $x=n$, denoted as $r_n$, there is a corresponding matrix $D_n$ and we can use its determinant to calculate the probability.

Is it just a coincidence or is there any theory that can explain this phenomenon?

Comment: My friend told me it is related to stochastic process but I haven't learnt that....

Comment: Could you post a source for the derivation of the formula?

Comment: Which formula, the probability or the determinant? As for the probability we can get the recursion formula $q_n = p q_{n+1} + (1-p) q_{n-1}$ by total probability formula. Thus we can get the formula. As for the determinant we can first get $det(D_n) = (1+\frac{q}{p})det(D_{n-1}) - \frac{q}{p}det(D_{n-2})$ by Laplace row expansions and then get the formula.

Comment: I think it is more reasonable to consider the following matrix: the sub- and super-diagonal being $(-1)$ and $(-q/p)$, making the row sum zero, with similar determinant. But I forget where this special form of matrix emerges...

Comment: Yes, the two determinants are the same. But I don't know why we need to make the row sum zero. Maybe it is because I don't know the relation between the probability and the determinant....

Comment: Oh I just recollect what it is. $(-1)D_(a+b)$ is the transition rate matrix of the "same" random walk but in continuous time. By $D_(a+b)$ I mean that altered one in my last comment. However I cannot think about a probability meaning for its determinant(or the absolute value of the determinant)...

Comment: What's the transition rate matrix? Is it a concept from stochastic theory?

Comment: I don't see it, but perhaps you can find some meaning by considering an $n \times n$ matrix determinant as the volume of a $n$-dimensional parallelepiped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Geometric_meaning

Comment: Try this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain

Comment: @ZhangQifan: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) for transition rate matrix.

Comment: No it's not the transition rate matrix--my fault. This is the transition probability underneath, with no relation to the transition rate. So this matrix has no probability meaning I think. I think this is just a coincidence...

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. I've found some related materials on the website you provided. It's related to Markov chain.